# Restart an Informatica session after fail, attempt N times or notify

Tags: workflow, informatica

I have an informatica worklow which I need it to be restarted in case of error.  In case it fails 2 o 3 times, it should send a notification.  Can you advise how to do this?

Comment: pls use shell/cmd script. You need to start it in the beginning of your load. It will check if workflow failed, restart it, if failed 2/3 times,mail the support team.

Comment: Thank you, do you have a sample of how to perform this? The call of the PC workflow for example and the validations of the results.